# How to get an int value from a query string in ASP.NE Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm implementing asp.net core project and I have a line of code like following:

```
var myAPIApplicantId = (from x in _context.Apiapplicant
                        where x.ApiRequestNo == apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApiRequestNo
                        select new { x.Id }).First();
```

After running the project I understand `myAPIApplicantId` contains `{ Id = 1148 }`. 
In another line of code, I have the following code:

```
int IntAPIApplicantID = Convert.ToInt32(myAPIApplicantId);
```

But it throws an error for type casting. Now I want to know how cant I get 1148 value to convert to int?

Comment: This is in no way a valid question. If the value of `myAPIApplicantId` is an interger, why convert to an int. Even if it is a string, the line of code `Convert.ToInt32` must work. If it is an object, the access the Id properly with `myAPIApplicantId.Id`

Comment: Thank you. Yes your answer is ok. But you answered me a loittle bit late because I had solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `id` like below:

```
var myAPIApplicantId = (from x in _context.Apiapplicant
                    where x.ApiRequestNo == apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApiRequestNo
                    select new { x.Id }).First();   //this generate an Anonymous Type like {Id=1}

int IntAPIApplicantID = myAPIApplicantId.Id;
```

The other way,you could change like below:

```
var myAPIApplicantId = _context.Apiapplicant
                               .Where(x.ApiRequestNo == apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApiRequestNo)
                               .Select(x => x.Id).First(); //this generate a Integer type

int IntAPIApplicantID = myAPIApplicantId;
```